# *** -[__NSDictionaryI release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1702e8a80 after upgrading from AlamoFire 3.x to AlamoFire 4.x and Swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am getting *** -[__NSDictionaryI release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1702e8a80 using Alamofire 4.4 and Xcode 8.3. As up now i have been able to trace the zombie but its frustating because i do not handle the object allocation, Alamofire does .

here´s my code

```
Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
    if response.result.isFailure {
        self.offlineError(self, selector: #selector(self.goToSales))
    } else {
        let sales = SalesViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sales , animated: true)
    }
}
```

also here you can find the screenshot form the Xcode Instrument console .

```
    Malloc/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:01.884.473   Foundation  newJSONValue
2   Retain  +1  2   00:01.884.497   Alamofire   0x10071df1b
3   Retain  +1  3   00:01.884.528   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
4   Release -1  2   00:01.884.529   Alamofire   0x10071dfef
5   Retain  +1  3   00:01.884.667   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
    Retain/Release (4)          00:01.884.679   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
10  Release -1  2   00:01.884.799   Alamofire   0x100719557
12  Retain  +1  2   00:01.884.902   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
13  Retain  +1  3   00:01.884.907   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
14  Retain  +1  4   00:01.884.907   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
15  Retain  +1  0   00:01.884.911   libswiftCore.dylib  _dynamicCastToExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags)
16  Retain  +1  5   00:01.884.912   APPName 0x1000fc367
17  Retain  +1  6   00:01.885.006   APPName 0x1000fc3c7
    Retain/Release (2)          00:01.885.046   APPName 0x10010364f
20  Release -1  5   00:01.885.060   APPName 0x1001035ff
21  Release -1  4   00:01.885.065   APPName 0x1000fc7bb
22  Release -1  3   00:01.885.067   APPName 0x1000fd3bb
23  Release -1  2   00:01.885.067   APPName 0x1000fd3d3
24  Release -1  1   00:01.885.068   APPName 0x1000fd3fb
25  Release -1  0   00:01.885.071   APPName 0x1000fd78f
26  Zombie      -1  00:01.885.746   Alamofire   0x10071148b
```

edit:

Stack with dSym enabled :

```
    Malloc/Autorelease (2)  +1      00:01.411.929   Foundation  newJSONValue
    Retain/Release (6)          00:01.411.943   Alamofire   0x100739f1b
    Retain/Release (4)          00:01.412.052   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
10  Retain  +1  4   00:01.412.141   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
11  Retain  +1  5   00:01.412.145   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
12  Retain  +1  6   00:01.412.146   libswiftCore.dylib  swift::metadataimpl::BufferValueWitnessesBase<swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::ObjCRetainableBox> >::initializeBufferWithCopyOfBuffer(swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::ValueBuffer*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)
13  Retain  +1  0   00:01.412.149   libswiftCore.dylib  _dynamicCastToExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags)
14  Retain  +1  7   00:01.412.150   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
15  Retain  +1  8   00:01.412.158   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
    Retain/Release (2)          00:01.412.167   AppName partial apply
18  Release -1  7   00:01.412.176   AppName 0x1001775e4
19  Release -1  6   00:01.412.180   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
20  Release -1  5   00:01.412.182   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
21  Release -1  4   00:01.412.182   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
22  Release -1  3   00:01.412.183   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
23  Release -1  2   00:01.412.186   AppName FLViewController.(checkStatus(Bool) -> ()).(closure #1)
26  Zombie      -1  00:01.412.268   Foundation  __NSOQSchedule_f
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you able to see what the dictionary is?  Does anything in the "APPName" frames have an opportunity to save a strong reference to it?  (If I'm remembering correctly, building with dsym enabled gets you symbols instead of addresses in Instruments.)

Comment: @PhillipMills i added the stack with the  symbols

Comment: Can you share the code for`offlineError()`?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue thanks to @PhillipMills suggestion of enabling  dSym .